# Class 'App\User' not found after adding a role in laravel Nova admin panel role permission

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, acl, laravel-nova, laravel-permission

I am using a laravel 8.7 with nova admin panel
I have added a permission package silvanite/novatoolpermissions

After adding a role gives error Class 'App\User' not found

I did have another error but that was cleaned with updating composer and publishing Nova. Now I can't access Nova because the error "Class "App\User" not found" is blocking my way after I log into Nova.

What can I do? I am using Laravel 8 which puts the User model in app\models.

Comment: do `silvanite/novatoolpermission` have any config? have you checked if it refers to `App\User`? though, i do curious where your `User` model is.

Comment: there is no config file for novatoolpermission

Comment: From time to time i just remove vendor, bootstrap/cache/*.php and reinstall dependencies, clear:cache, config:clear, optimize and then it usually works. Also, i think it should be App\Models\User so try and publish the config with artisan:publish and edit to correct model name inside the published config